# Non zero derivative

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $p,q,x,y:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be $C^1 ((a,b))$ functions. Knowing that the function:

$F_v:(a,b)\times (a,b)\to\mathbb{R};\ v\in (0,1),\ F_v (u,\tilde{u})=y(\tilde{u})(p(u)-p(\tilde{u}))-x(\tilde{u})(q(u)-q(\tilde{u}))+v(x(u)y(\tilde{u})-x(\tilde{u})y(u))$

has the property that $F_v(u,\tilde u)=0\ \Longleftrightarrow\ u=\tilde{u}$,

is it true that the function:

$f:(a,b)\times (0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by:

$f(u,v):=\dfrac{\partial F_v}{\partial u} (u,u)=p'(u)y(u)-q'(u)x(u)+v(x'(u)y(u)-x(u)y'(u))$, is NEVER equal to $0$?

I've struggled a lot to find a counterexample, but it seems to be a good statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
\begin{align*}
x(u) &= 0, \\
y(u) &= 1, \\
p(u) &= \left(u-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^3.
\end{align*}

My intuition for constructing this example was to start from the simplest possible case (constant functions) and noticing that if $x=0$ and $y=1$, I needed an injective $p$ whose derivative vanishes at a point.

Comment: That helped me a lot! Thanks!